# jquery datepicker plugin function doesn't work in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, firefox, datepicker

I use two datepicker with the following propertys:

datepicker: dont show past dates

datepicker_2: only show next 5 days based on date in #datepicker

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
    /* dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',    */  
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: '+2y',
    onSelect: function(date){
      var selectedDate = new Date(date);
      var msecsInADay =0;
   var msecsInADay2 =432000000; //5 Days
      var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
   var maxDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay2);
      $("#datepicker_2").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
      $("#datepicker_2").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", maxDate );      
  } 
 }); 
}); 
        
$(function() {
 $('#datepicker_2').datepicker({ 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="leaving day" id="datepicker" required="true" placeholder="leaving day" />

<input type="text" name="arrival day" id="datepicker_2" required="true" placeholder="arrival day" />
```

Woks fine under chrome! But not in Firefox and IE.
In this codesnippet it doesn't seem to work, too.

I think there is something wrong with the "new Date()", but I don't see the mistake...

**EDIT**

It only works with datefomat mm/dd/yy, not with dd.mm.yy

The notworking date seems to be invalid.

Comment: Sorry, there is something to add:

Comment: it works fine, but when I change the dateFormat to dd.mm.yy it doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I have an answer.

The problem is the dateFormat. It has to be in format mm/dd/yy or an other format from this list: http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html

For displaying an other format I used altFormat and altField in the same datepicker input-field.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
 dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
   altFormat: "dd. M. yy",
   altField: "#datepicker",
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: '+2y',
    onSelect: function(date){
      var selectedDate = new Date(date);
      var msecsInADay =0;
   var msecsInADay2 =432000000; //5 Days
      var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
   var maxDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay2);
      $("#datepicker_2").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
      $("#datepicker_2").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", maxDate );      
  } 
 }); 
}); 
        
$(function() {
 $('#datepicker_2').datepicker({ 
      dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
      altFormat: "dd. M. yy",
      altField: "#datepicker_2"
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="leaving day" id="datepicker" required="true" placeholder="leaving day" />

<input type="text" name="arrival day" id="datepicker_2" required="true" placeholder="arrival day" />
```